# Handling file watchers in Vagrant shared folder

Tags: vagrant, babeljs, file-watcher

I'm using Vagrant shared folder to develop a project using babel as a file watcher.

However, most likely, because of time difference between host and guest machine whenever I change a file the watcher doesn't see the changes and doesn't recompile modified assets, making the whole development environment useless.

I've tried changing the sync strategy to RSync but it only works when the file A is changed to A' but when I change B to B' it works as well, but reverts file A' back to A.

Is there any workflow that'd allow me to develop files in shared folder, still firing up file watcher hooks inside the guest machine?

Comment: you can look at using `nfs` as shared folder type to improve performance - however even though the changes are not picked up immediately it should still comes within seconds

Comment: I'll check this, but lack of `nfs` support on Windows would be a poor half-measure

Comment: No success with `nfs` still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't watch for file notifications on a shared folder. You have to use something like rsync auto or a third party file watcher like https://github.com/AgentCosmic/xnotify